# Clearing when the date expires

Tags: php, symfony, listener

I have a problem with placement code.

I wrote a service to upload a temporary file, before registering advertisement (entity name) and uploaded real files.

If somebody uploads a few photos to a form and leave the page without registering, I want to delete this file from database/server.

My idea is: clear all files after 2 hours from uploading the file and I don't know where put this functionality?

A few ideas:

1. Method in service + CRON
2. Event listener after every request
3. ...?

Comment: Cron sounds good

Comment: 4.... *"I tried............"*

Comment: ^ so where's that?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new [console command](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html) that will delete all these files. And then set a cron job executing this command every 2 hours. This can be acceptable.

If I understood well a user uploads file and then he decides not to finish the registration (email confirmation e.g.). Better solution can be to allow him to upload file after registration is finished.

Comment: Thanks for answer. You are right in the second paragraph, better idea is wait for save advertisment and next upload files.